# Issues with installing OpenCV for Android on Eclipse: various errors including "not found in PATH"

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, opencv, android-ndk

I'm trying to install OpenCV for Android on Eclipse (Windows 8). I've followed thee tutorial found here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N2onPuDZQVY step-by-step but still run into errors when I try to build any of the sample projects. These are the errors I get in my console:

```
16:10:33 **** Incremental Build of configuration Default for project OpenCV Sample - 15         puzzle ****
"C:\\Dev\\android-ndk-r9d\\ndk-build.cmd" all 
Android NDK: WARNING: APP_PLATFORM android-9 is larger than android:minSdkVersion 8 in     ./AndroidManifest.xml    
C:/Dev/android-ndk-r9d/build/core/add-application.mk:187: *** Android NDK: Aborting...    .  Stop.
Android NDK: Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file: ./jni/Android.mk
```

And I see this in the "Problems" tab:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required     .class files    Video.java  /OpenCV Library - 2.4.9/src/org/opencv/video    line 1      Java Problem

The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved    OpenCV Sample -     camera-calibration      Unknown Java Problem

Unable to resolve target 'android-14'   OpenCV Library - 2.4.9      Unknown     Android Target Problem

The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class     file for java.lang.Object. Fix the build path then try building this project    OpenCV     Library - 2.4.9      Unknown Java Problem

Unable to resolve target 'android-11'   OpenCV Sample - face-detection          Unknown Android Target Problem

The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library 'C:\Dev\OpenCV-    2.4.9-android-sdk\sdk\java\bin\opencv library - 2.4.9.jar'  OpenCV Sample - camera-    calibration      Build path  Build Path Problem

Invalid project path: Include path not found (\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-    libstdc++\4.6\libs\armeabi-v7a\include). OpenCV Sample - face-detection          pathentry   Path Entry Problem

The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved    OpenCV Sample -     face-detection      Unknown Java Problem

Invalid project path: Include path not found (\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-    libstdc++\4.6\include).  OpenCV Sample - face-detection      pathentry   Path Entry     Problem

Program "\ndk-build.cmd" not found in PATH  OpenCV Sample - face-detection              C/C++ Problem

Unable to resolve target 'android-11'   OpenCV Sample - 15 puzzle           Unknown Android Target Problem

The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library 'C:\Dev\OpenCV-    2.4.9-android-sdk\sdk\java\bin\opencv library - 2.4.9.jar'  OpenCV Sample - 15 puzzle           Build path  Build Path Problem

The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library 'C:\Dev\OpenCV-    2.4.9-android-sdk\sdk\java\bin\opencv library - 2.4.9.jar'  OpenCV Sample - face-    detection      Build path  Build Path Problem

Unable to resolve target 'android-11'   OpenCV Sample - camera-calibration          Unknown Android Target Problem

Invalid project path: Include path not found (\platforms\android-9\arch-    arm\usr\include).   OpenCV Sample - face-detection      pathentry   Path Entry     Problem

The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved    OpenCV Sample - 15     puzzle       Unknown Java Problem

*** Android NDK: Aborting...    .  Stop.    OpenCV Sample - 15 puzzle         line 187, external location: C:\Dev\android-ndk-r9d\build\core\add-application.mk   C/C++ Problem
```

Where am I going wrong? My C/C++ Build command is: ${NDKROOT}\ndk-build.cmd and I have the environment variable properly defined with the full path of the folder that contains the ndk-build.cmd file. Let me know if there is any other information I need to provide. Any help would be much appreciated - this has been defeating me for a whole week now!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can find some conference in http://johnhany.net/2014/04/using-opencv-on-android/.
点击C/C++ General->Paths and Symbols->Includes，在GNU C++中添加如下路径：

```
            ${NDKROOT}/platforms/android-15/arch-arm/usr/include

            ${NDKROOT}/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/include

            ${NDKROOT}/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi-v7a/include
```

in my ndk r12b there is no 4.6 path.